# FirebaseAuth throws error macCatalyst swift

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, mac-catalyst

When I try to use the `signIn` and `createUser` methods, it works perfectly fine until I use **macCatalyst**. It somehow throws an error:

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17995 "An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_KEYCHAIN_ERROR, NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemAdd (-34018), NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered}

Here's my code:

`create new user`

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailAdress, password: password1, completion: {
   result, error in
   guard error == nil else {
        print("Couldn't log in (error: \(error!))")
        //Some code here
   }
//Some code here
}
```

I made sure that the user is logged out before I execute this code.

`log in`

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailAdress, password: password1) { result, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Couldn't log in (error: \(error!))")
        //Some code here
    }
    //Some code here
}
```

I've tried to print out as much as possible, but it didn't help me.
I've also looked if the application was opened twice (because this caused a keychain error once).
I've tried to enable key chain sharing.